# Strange Behavior of window.location.hash Containing Dots / Periods

Tags: javascript, html, url, hash, history.js

Never seen this or could imagine. My URL looks similar to this:

```
 www.site.com/root/path1/path2/123/some-path-1/page.1.2.html
```

At some point I update URL with hash so dynamic user interaction would reflect the URL address to send a link to a friend:

```
 window.location.hash = 'key=SomeValue';
```

It works perfect for me almost in all cases, except when SomeValue contains dots:

```
 window.location.hash = 'key=SomeValueA.B.';
```

With the above URL becomes:

```
 www.site.com/root/path1/path2/123/some-path-1/key=SomeValueA.B.
```

instead of 
     www.site.com/root/path1/path2/123/some-path-1/page.1.2.html#key=SomeValueA.B.

I cannot imagine what is wrong here and I cannot reproduce it in jsfiddle. I use the custom written hash manager class for this:

```
var hashUrlManager = function(){
 var getHash = function(){       
    return (window.location.hash) ? window.location.hash.substring(1) : "";
 };
 return{
    getHash : getHash,
    getParam : function(k){
        return Util.getParameter(k,"?"+getHash());
    },
    setParam : function(k,v){
        var h = getHash();
        var vNow = hashUrlManager.getParam(k);
        if(vNow==""){
            if(window.location.href.indexOf("#")==-1){
                window.location.hash = k+"="+v;
            }else{
                window.location.hash = h+((h=="")?"":"&")+k+"="+v;
            }
        }else if(vNow!==v){
            window.location.hash = window.location.hash.replace(k+"="+vNow,k+"="+v);                
        }
    },
    removeParam : function(k){
        var v = hashUrlManager.getParam(k);
        var s = k+"="+v;
        if(window.location.hash.indexOf("&"+s)!=-1)s="&"+s;
        window.location.hash = window.location.hash.replace(s,"");
    }
 };
}();

hashUrlManager.setParam('key','SomeValueA.B.');
```

Note: I do use History.js, if that matters, and jQuery on the page.

Comment: Have you checked for instances of @window.location@ in the rest of the code?  If you can reproduce it in your application but not in jsfiddle, perhaps the problem is happening somewhere you don't expect.

Comment: what's surprising me is that this is happening only when dots are present in the hash; it works at all times without dots.

Answer (score 1):

I've come across the same issue. I reproduced it successfully on http://jsbin.com/aMUdejA/1/edit?html,output . It's the coexistence of jQuery (both 1.x & 2.x versions) & History.js.

I filed an issue https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/issues/363